# Calculate the limit $\lim_{t\to 0^+} \frac{e^{-x^2/4t}}{t^{3/2}}.$

Tags: calculus, analysis, limits

I am trying to calculate the limit $\lim_{t\to 0^+} \frac{e^{-x^2/4t}}{t^{3/2}}.$ I know the answer should be $0$ as the exponential decaps more rapidly, but I don't know how to show this, as I tried using L'hopital but it doesn't work. I would greatly appreciate any help.

Comment: Can't you just square that and use L'Hospital?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For example, we can do a substitution:

$$u=\frac1t\;,\;\;\text{so}\;\;t\to0^+\implies u\to\infty\implies$$

$$\lim_{t\to0^+}\frac{e^{-x^2/4t}}{t^{3/2}}=\lim_{u\to\infty}\frac{e^{-\frac{x^2u}4}}{\frac1{u^{3/2}}}=\lim_{u\to\infty}\frac{u^{3/2}}{e^{\frac{x^2u}4}}\stackrel{\text{l'Hospital}}=\lim_{u\to\infty}\frac32\frac{u^{1/2}}{\frac{x^2}4e^{\frac{x^2u}4}}\stackrel{\text{l'H}}=$$

$$=\lim_{u\to\infty}\frac34\frac1{\frac{x^4}{16}u^{1/2}e^{\frac{x^2u}4}}=0$$

Of course, we could have saved all the above if we already know that exponential "kills" polynomial...